# Deploying on Heroku: appplication error H10 error, Cannot find Module postman request (node.js)

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy my weather on Heroku (a node.js project), everything works fine locally but after uploading to Heroku it says application error.

I did Heroku logs to see what the problem was and it says cannot find model postman-request followed by a H10 error. I tried changing the port, but it didn't work.

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("server UP" + PORT)
});
```

I also tried to npm install postman-request, didn't work. What can I try next?

```
2022-08-22T15:06:09.436614+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bash` by user kkyun25@naver.com
2022-08-22T15:06:12.131225+00:00 heroku[run.9686]: State changed from starting to up
2022-08-22T15:06:12.183900+00:00 heroku[run.9686]: Awaiting client
2022-08-22T15:06:12.199410+00:00 heroku[run.9686]: Starting process with command `bash`
2022-08-22T15:24:35.956444+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-08-22T15:24:37.834316+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-08-22T15:24:39.489190+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-22T15:24:39.489202+00:00 app[web.1]: > web-server@1.0.0 start
2022-08-22T15:24:39.489202+00:00 app[web.1]: > node src/app.js
2022-08-22T15:24:39.489203+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-22T15:24:39.628673+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
2022-08-22T15:24:39.628674+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2022-08-22T15:24:39.628675+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-08-22T15:24:39.628675+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-22T15:24:39.628675+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'postman-request'
2022-08-22T15:24:39.628676+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2022-08-22T15:24:39.628676+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/src/utils/geocode.js
2022-08-22T15:24:39.628676+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/src/app.js
2022-08-22T15:24:39.628677+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
2022-08-22T15:24:39.628680+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
2022-08-22T15:24:39.628680+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
2022-08-22T15:24:39.628680+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-08-22T15:24:39.628681+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/utils/geocode.js:1:16)
2022-08-22T15:24:39.628681+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
2022-08-22T15:24:39.628682+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
2022-08-22T15:24:39.628682+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
2022-08-22T15:24:39.628682+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
2022-08-22T15:24:39.628683+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19) {
2022-08-22T15:24:39.628683+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-08-22T15:24:39.628684+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/src/utils/geocode.js', '/app/src/app.js' ]
2022-08-22T15:24:39.628684+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-08-22T15:24:39.759614+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-08-22T15:24:40.043164+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-08-22T15:24:40.051183+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-08-22T15:24:41.841461+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-08-22T15:24:43.532121+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-22T15:24:43.532133+00:00 app[web.1]: > web-server@1.0.0 start
2022-08-22T15:24:43.532133+00:00 app[web.1]: > node src/app.js
2022-08-22T15:24:43.532134+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-22T15:24:43.669987+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
2022-08-22T15:24:43.669989+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2022-08-22T15:24:43.669992+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-08-22T15:24:43.669993+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-08-22T15:24:43.669993+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'postman-request'
2022-08-22T15:24:43.669993+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2022-08-22T15:24:43.669994+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/src/utils/geocode.js
2022-08-22T15:24:43.669994+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/src/app.js
2022-08-22T15:24:43.669995+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
2022-08-22T15:24:43.669995+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
2022-08-22T15:24:43.669995+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
2022-08-22T15:24:43.669996+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-08-22T15:24:43.669996+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/utils/geocode.js:1:16)
2022-08-22T15:24:43.669996+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
2022-08-22T15:24:43.669997+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
2022-08-22T15:24:43.669997+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
2022-08-22T15:24:43.669997+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
2022-08-22T15:24:43.669998+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19) {
2022-08-22T15:24:43.669998+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-08-22T15:24:43.669998+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/src/utils/geocode.js', '/app/src/app.js' ]
2022-08-22T15:24:43.669998+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-08-22T15:24:43.805848+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Comment: Well, do you expect that module to be available? Have you declared it as a dependency? Please show us your `package.json`.

Comment: Hey! thank you for answering!  I think it is declared in the dependency, below is my package.json file                                                     {
  "name": "web-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "hbs": "^4.2.0",
    "postman-request": "^2.88.1-postman.31",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "require": "^2.4.20"
  }
}

Comment: That should be [edit]ed into your question. As you can see, it is very hard to read in a comment, and comments aren't good for important information as they can be deleted at any time for any reason.

Comment: Is that file in the root directory of your project? Do you have any other `package.json` files? Are you sure it's committed?